# Can SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute be applied to COM Interop interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

Can `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute` be applied to COM Interop interfaces to improve performance, or is it only suitable for optimizing native function calls? [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.suppressunmanagedcodesecurityattribute.aspx):

> This attribute is only effective when applied to PInvoke methods (or classes that contain PInvoke methods) or the definition of an interface through which interop calls will be made. It will be ignored in all other contexts.

However, I'm not absolutely sure wether that includes COM interop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or the definition of an interface through which interop calls will be made

That talks about a COM interface.  The attribute has to be applied to the interface declaration to be effective.  Do note how hard that is to get, COM interfaces are normally declared in the interop library that's generated by Tlbimp.exe.  Which is missing an option to auto-generate the attribute.  Realistically, you can only do this if you declare the interfaces yourself.

Comment: Every time I've used TlbImp, the produced code was a mess with weird types, so I had to decompile the code and declare all types myself... By the way, do you know [what `MethodImpl(InternalCall, Runtime)` is for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254109/what-does-methodimplattributeinternalcall-runtime-do-for-methods-of-com-inter)? TlbImp generates it too...

Comment: It is just an attribute to tell the jitter that the code for the method is elsewhere and that the method should never be called directly.

Comment: Does it have any substantial effects? Is it better to add this attribute or not?

Comment: Nothing substantial.  It isn't necessary.

Comment: The "InternalCall" attribute is required for COM Interop to work on Mono, though. The Mono JIT will just crash if this attribute is missing. (At least on Linux; didn't test with Mono on Windows.)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx), you can have Tlbimp.exe apply the SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity attribute to your COM interfaces by passing the "/unsafe" switch. I can confirm that it works as advertised with a simple test TLB.