# What does MethodImplAttribute(InternalCall, Runtime) do for methods of COM Interop interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

In [Windows API Code Pack for .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), many methods of COM Interop interfaces are decorated with `MethodImplAttribute`, for example:

```
internal interface IShellItem
{
    [PreserveSig]
    [MethodImpl(
        MethodImplOptions.InternalCall,
        MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    HResult BindToHandler(
        [In] IntPtr pbc, [In] ref Guid bhid, [In] ref Guid riid,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out IShellFolder ppv);
```

Documentation for [`MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) value says:

> The call is internal, that is, it calls a method that is implemented within the common language runtime.

Documentation for [`MethodCodeType.Runtime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k10sb5f.aspx) says:

> Specifies that the method implementation is provided by the runtime.

But, if I understand correctly, neither statement is correct. [`IShellItem` is implemented in *shell32.dll*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), according to MSDN. *shell32.dll* is not a part of CLR. What's interesting, not all methods have the `MethodImplAttribute`. `IShellFolder` does, `IShellLinkW` doesn't, `IShellLibrary` does, `IPersistStream` doesn't etc.

Why is `MethodImplAttribute` applied to some of the COM Interop interfaces? What does it mean in this case and how does it modify behavior of interop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is just a side-effect from the way the Microsoft programmer obtained the interface declaration.  Some of the shell interfaces are available in a type library, like IShellItem, so the easiest way to get them into source code is to run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library and a disassembler to decompile the assembly into C# code.  Which also brings in the extra attributes that Tlbimp.exe generates, like [MethodImpl].

Other interfaces are not available in a type library, like IShellLinkW and IPersistStream, nor can a type library be generated from the IDL so the programmer had no choice but to type them in himself.  He skipped the unnecessary stuff.

And no, [MethodImpl] isn't critical here.  These are interface types so there is no method anyway.  Tlbimp.exe just isn't terribly sophisticated about it.